# Connection problems with MySQL and Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql

Could anyone help me out here? What am I supposed to do to fix this problem?

```
try
        {
            /*Connect to MySQL database */
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(127.0.0.1, root, psswrd);
            System.out.println("Connection established...");
            System.out.println();
```

> Error: Multiple markers at this line
>     - The left-hand side of an assignment must be a      variable
>     - Syntax error on token ".0", invalid    AssignmentOperator
>     - root cannot be resolved to a variable

Answer (score 0):

The connection string should be in this form: `jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db_name`, and you should load mysql jdbc driver before establishing the connection as follow:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```